# Ray box intersection with first hitpoint known

Tags: algorithm, 3d, glsl, intersection, raycasting

I have a point placed on a cube. I also have a direction. My goal is to get the position on the side of the cube intersecting with the direction vector.

I am doing this in GLSL (example code doesn't need to be GLSL). I would think this case would be solved with a ray box intersection function, but I can't get it to work at all.

```
float IntersectBox(vec3 orig, vec3 dir, vec3 box)
{
    vec3 t1 = (- orig) / dir; // cube starts at 0,0,0
    vec3 t2 = (box - orig) / dir; // cube ends at box vector coordinates 

    vec3 real_min = min(t1, t2);
    vec3 real_max = max(t1, t2);

    float minmax = min( min(real_max.x, real_max.y), real_max.z);
    return minmax;
}
```

I then add the length to the original position:

```
pos  += normalize(rayDir) * IntersectBox(pos, rayDir, vec3(grid));
```

### Edit

Adding additional explanation.

I have a cube:

```
_____?___
|     \  |
|      \ |    . is start point - this is known.
|       \.    / is direction (roughly -.3, .8 here) - this is known
|________|    ? is the exit point - which I need to find out
```

On the cube, I have a point of entrance. Above it is the dot. I also have a direction. Now I need to find out the point where the ray leaves the cube, exactly where this happens. See the question mark, this point of exit I need to find out.

Of course this is a 2 dimensional case, but I need it for 3 dimensions.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please describe more what you are trying to do, maybe with an example.

Comment: I've explained thorough enough now I hope.

Comment: It all lies in the positive octant. It might be that I have to intersect with planes, but I'm hoping there is an easier way than plane intersection with the sides of the cube.

Comment: Since `max(t1,t2)` is giving a 'forward' parametric value for X,Y,Z, it won't give spurious t=0 values (unless the ray touches an edge). Note that if one of the components of `dir` is (0), earlier versions of GLSL don't specify the result - I believe newer versions *do* set the result +/-Infinity, like standard floating-point. But I think the problem is that `rayDir` isn't normalized prior to being passed to `IntersectBox`, and yet the normalized vector is being scaled by that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a ray `R = {u*t + v|t}` and a plane `P = {p|<n, p> = d}`, it is straightforward to determine the value of `t` at which `R` and `P` intersect if it exists.  That is, it is straightforward to determine `t > 0` such that `<n, u*t + v> = d` if it exists.

Your cube has six planar sides: `P[i], i = 1..6`. For each side `i`, determine if the ray `R` intersects `P[i]` for some value `t[i]`. If any side `P[i]` does not intersect `R`, remove that side from consideration.

For each plane `P[i]` that does intersect `R`, `u*t[i] + v` is the intersection position. If any such intersection position is outside of the cube, remove it from consideration.

The first intersection position `u*t[i] + v` that is in the cube is the position you are looking for.